# Стандарты для умных домов и вещей

Tags: умный-дом

Какие существуют стандарты или протоколы для связи элементов умного дома? Если я буду выпускать свою умную лампочку, каким стандартам я должен придерживаться, чтобы она работала с Google Home, Xiaomi Mi Home, Amazon Alexa и тд.?

Comment: С тем что вы перечислили - заключить договор, и реализовать апи по предоставленой документации =)
Из популярных среди самодельщиков - MQTT, LoRa, RS485, CAN, BLE, NRF24+ и еще пара десятков именно популярных, эти первые что вспомнил из массовых и на что заглядывался сам

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Так а где эту документацию по api найти?

Comment: Подписать договор с указанными компаниями и получить его под NDA, кроме возможно амазона, про них не в курсе.